# Is there a better way to update sqlite table?

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, sqlite

I have been using the following code for updating data in my sqlite table but have always thought to be not optimal way of doing it. Basically since I dont know what and where data in my two-dimensional NSMutableArray has been updated by the user what I am doing is deleting the table creating it again with all the columns and then inserting data in it.

Is there a better way of doing this by some sort of data comparison between the table and my array. Do point out any other malpractice that come in your sight in the following:

```
-(void)updateCurrentItemsData:(NSArray *) dataArray
{
NSArray *paths= NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
gameDBPath=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"gameData.sqlite"];
const char *dbpath = [gameDBPath UTF8String];
int test;
char *errMsg;
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &gamedatabase)==SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM currentitems"];
    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
    test=sqlite3_exec(gamedatabase, query_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg);
    if (test!=0) NSLog(@"exec is 5 1 %i",test);

    const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS currentitems(itemid, name, quantity, damaged, price)";
    test=sqlite3_exec(gamedatabase, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg);
    if (test!=0) NSLog(@"exec is 5 2 %i",test);
for (int i=0; i<dataArray.count; i++)
{
    NSString *querySQL= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO currentitems(itemid, name, quantity, damaged, price) VALUES('%i','%@','%i','%i','%i')",[[[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:0] intValue],[[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:1],[[[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:2] intValue],[[[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:3] intValue],[[[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:4] intValue]];
    //NSLog(@"querySQL is %@",querySQL);

    const char *insert_stmt= [querySQL UTF8String];
    test=sqlite3_exec(gamedatabase, insert_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg);
    if (test!=0) NSLog(@"exec is 5 3 %i",test);
}
    sqlite3_finalize(statementgame);
    sqlite3_close(gamedatabase);
}

}
```

Thanks for looking :)

Answer (score 0):

You may increase performance using transactions - just look at slightly modified code below:

```
-(void)updateCurrentItemsData:(NSArray *) dataArray
{
NSArray *paths= NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
gameDBPath=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"gameData.sqlite"];
const char *dbpath = [gameDBPath UTF8String];
int test;
char *errMsg;
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &gamedatabase)==SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM currentitems"];
    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
    test=sqlite3_exec(gamedatabase, query_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg);
    if (test!=0) NSLog(@"exec is 5 1 %i",test);

    const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS currentitems(itemid, name, quantity, damaged, price)";
    test=sqlite3_exec(gamedatabase, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg);
    if (test!=0) NSLog(@"exec is 5 2 %i",test);

sqlite3_exec(gamedatabase, "BEGIN TRANSACTION", NULL, NULL, NULL);

for (int i=0; i<dataArray.count; i++)
{
    NSString *querySQL= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO currentitems(itemid, name, quantity, damaged, price) VALUES('%i','%@','%i','%i','%i')",[[[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:0] intValue],[[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:1],[[[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:2] intValue],[[[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:3] intValue],[[[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:4] intValue]];
    //NSLog(@"querySQL is %@",querySQL);

    const char *insert_stmt= [querySQL UTF8String];
    test=sqlite3_exec(gamedatabase, insert_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg);
    if (test!=0) NSLog(@"exec is 5 3 %i",test);
}

sqlite3_exec(gamedatabase, "COMMIT TRANSACTION", NULL, NULL, NULL);

    sqlite3_finalize(statementgame);
    sqlite3_close(gamedatabase);
}

}
```